# Can not install ng-bootstap with angular 16.1.3

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to use `ng-bootstrap` with `Angular 16.1.3`, while trying to install it, it gave me below error:

```
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: data2-pdf@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@16.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"16.1.3" from @angular/animations@16.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"16.1.3" from @angular/platform-browser@16.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"16.1.3" from @angular/forms@16.1.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"^16.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^16.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"16.1.3" from @angular/common@16.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"16.1.3" from @angular/forms@16.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"^16.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"16.1.3" from @angular/platform-browser@16.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"16.1.3" from @angular/forms@16.1.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"^16.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!   7 more (@angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"15.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@16.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"16.1.4" from @angular/forms@16.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^16.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^16.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@15.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"15.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-12T23_56_47_856Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-12T23_56_47_856Z-debug-0.log
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.
```

Any help how to resolve this?

also my package.json file looks like

```
{
  "name": "data2-pdf",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.29",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What command are you using to use ng-bootstrap?

Comment: Agree with Ajay, what version of ng bootstrap are you trying to install, also what does your package.json look like

Comment: @AjayManagaon,  I used add command to add it (ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap). also my package.json is updated in the question

Answer (score 1):

try `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force`

Answer (score 0):

try add [manually](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

```
ng add bootstrap
ng add @popperjs/core
ng add @angular/localize
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

NOTE: In the docs the dependencies are

```
ng-bootstrap 15.x.x
angular      16.0.0 
bootstrap    5.2.3
popper       2.11.6
```

I don't know if there confict using Angular 16.1.0